# We are not able to get the value from property

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Here is My Code

```
public abstract class LayoutMetadata
{
    public abstract Guid StaticId { get; }
}

Public MonthlyRor:LayoutMetadata
{
        //Here we assigned static value to StaticId
     public override Guid StaticId => new Guid("1188644E-C754-4121-9625-1EDD361455D3");
}
```

```
var type = typeof(LayoutMetadata).Assembly.SafeGetTypes().Where(t => !t.IsAbstract && t != typeof(LayoutMetadata)).ToList();
var test=first.GetProperty("StaticId").GetValue(first, null);
```

I tried

`var test=first.GetProperty("StaticId").GetValue(first, null);`

but throws

> "Object does not match target type" exception

Please suggest any solution on this.

Comment: What is `first` here? What's its type?

Comment: We Took the first in the list

Comment: like this var first=type.first();

Comment: `type` is collection of types. And `first` will be first type of them. So `first` here is not an object of MonthlyRor nor LayoutMetadata. That's why you are getting this error. You need to create an instance of type `first` to access it's property.

Comment: if "first" is of type System.Type, of course you will not have "StaticID" in there. You need an instance of type LayoutMetadata. There is not object of this type in your code.

Comment: Shouldn't your `where` clause be: `t => !t.IsAbstract && typeof(LayoutMetadata).IsAssignableFrom(t)` rather than what you have?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you seem to be misunderstanding types and instances of the objects of that type you want to retrieve informacion from.

`type` in your code should be the *type* of the object you want to inspect and `first` should be an instance of type `type` you'd like to inspect. If thats the case, then your code should look like this:

```
var test = type.GetProperty("StaticId").GetValue(first, null);
```

Note that `GetProperty` needs to be invoked from the type object (`type`), and the instance of the object you want to inspect is passed as an argument to the method `GetValue`. A trivial example that makes it clear:

```
var p = new Person();
var t = p.GetType();
var name = t.GetProperty("Name").GetValue(p, null);
```